# Can a set containing a string of length $\omega_0$ be well-ordered by substring total order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I originally asked the quesiton here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411731/can-a-set-containing-a-string-of-infinite-length-be-well-ordered-by-substring-to

But right after posting the question, I lost my unregistered account, and as I need to edit the question, I am posting the question here:

The order $\leq$ on strings is defined as follows: $a\leq b$ with $a = a_1..$ and $b = b_1...$ being finite or infinite strings if and only if $\exists n \in (\mathbb{N}^{+} \cup \omega_0)$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0<k\leq n$, $a_k=b_k$.

Shortly said, $a\leq b$ if the substring starting from the first character to some $n$th character is shared by $b$ from the first character to some $n$th character. (string itself can be a substring of itself.) $\mathbb{N}^{+}$ refers to positive integers.

As $n$ can now be $\omega_0$, which is infinite ordinal, my question is:

Character set is $\Sigma$, and a string is represented as a set by each character itself being a set inside the string set. For example, string $jlm$, with $j,l,m \in \Sigma$, is represented as a set by $\{(j,1),(l,2),(m,3)\}$.

Suppose one builds a set $X$ like this:

Start from a finite character set $\Sigma$.

At step 1, choose any one character $c$ from $\Sigma$ and include $c$ into $X$; in other words, $c \in X$. $c=S_1$.

At step K (assuming $K \in \mathbb{N}$), start with a string $S$ added to $X$ at step $K-1$. choose any character $d$ from $\Sigma$ and append $d$ right to $S$. Call the new string $S_K$.

At step $\omega_0$, $S_{\omega_0} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}^{+}} S_k$.

In such a case, can set $X$ be said to be totally-ordered properly? (I am asking this question, because $\omega_0$ is technically inaccessible by successor operation. The above assumes away the possibility of reaching step $\omega_0$. But I am not sure if this is allowed.)

Comment: This question needs to be removed. It's in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411790/is-total-substring-well-ordering-of-a-set-containing-omega-0-length-string-po

Comment: By your definition $jlm = mjl = mlj = \ldots$. Are you sure, that you want to define it this way?

Answer (score 1):

If we allow strings of infinite length then we have no way to explicitly describe any well-order of that set, and especially the lexical order is not a well-order.
The reason is that even if we pick just two letter $a,b\in\Sigma$, then the (countably) infinite strings over these letters can be bijected with the power set of $\mathbb N$ (per $w\mapsto\{\,x\in\mathbb N\mid w_x=a\,\}$), or with $\mathbb R$ if you prefer; and those sets cannot be well-ordered unless by pure faith (i.e., the Axiom of Choice is needed).